# ANDROID :: custom ListView show only first LinearLayout Child

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

HERE is my xml for custom ListView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.prototype.auinsight.schedual_listview"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:id="@+id/wrapper">

    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:id="@+id/imgDay" android:layout_weight=".1"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"/>
        <com.prototype.auinsight.schedual_listview.CustomView_Schedule
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:id="@+id/view"
                custom:labelColor="@android:color/white"
                custom:timelineColor="@color/slate"
                android:layout_weight=".8"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>
        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:id="@+id/imgUpDown" android:scaleType="fitXY" android:src="@drawable/down"
                android:layout_weight=".1" android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="12dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/txtTime1" android:text="09:00" android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp" android:paddingBottom="5dp" android:textSize="20sp"/>
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ENGLISH IV"
                android:id="@+id/txtSubject1" android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp" android:paddingBottom="5dp" android:textSize="20sp"
                android:background="@color/subject_alizarin" android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/txtTime2" android:text="09:00" android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp" android:paddingBottom="5dp" android:textSize="20sp"/>
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ENGLISH IV"
                android:id="@+id/txtSubject2" android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp" android:paddingBottom="5dp" android:textSize="20sp"
                android:background="@color/subject_alizarin" android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/txtTime3" android:text="09:00" android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp" android:paddingBottom="5dp" android:textSize="20sp"/>
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ENGLISH IV"
                android:id="@+id/txtSubject3" android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp" android:paddingBottom="5dp" android:textSize="20sp"
                android:background="@color/subject_alizarin" android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/txtTime4" android:text="09:00" android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp" android:paddingBottom="5dp" android:textSize="20sp"/>
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ENGLISH IV"
                android:id="@+id/txtSubject4" android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp" android:paddingBottom="5dp" android:textSize="20sp"
                android:background="@color/subject_alizarin" android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/txtTime5" android:text="09:00" android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp" android:paddingBottom="5dp" android:textSize="20sp"/>
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ENGLISH IV"
                android:id="@+id/txtSubject5" android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp" android:paddingBottom="5dp" android:textSize="20sp"
                android:background="@color/subject_alizarin" android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

HERE is my Adapter

```
   @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        viewHolder vh = null;

        if(v == null){

            vh = new viewHolder();
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.schedual_listview,null);
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_middle_listview);

            vh.wrapper = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.wrapper);
            vh.imgDay = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgDay);
            vh.customView = (CustomView_Schedule) v.findViewById(R.id.view);
            vh.txtTime1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtTime1);
            vh.txtTime2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtTime2);
            vh.txtTime3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtTime3);
            vh.txtTime4 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtTime4);
            vh.txtTime5 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtTime5);
            vh.txtSubject1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtSubject1);
            vh.txtSubject2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtSubject2);
            vh.txtSubject3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtSubject3);
            vh.txtSubject4 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtSubject4);
            vh.txtSubject5 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtSubject5);


            v.setTag(vh);

        }else{
            vh = (viewHolder)v.getTag();
        }

        Schedule_lvItem schedule_lvItem = scheduleLvItems.get(position);

        vh.imgDay.setImageResource(schedule_lvItem.getDay());
        vh.customView.setSubjectData(schedule_lvItem.getSubjectData());
        vh.txtTime1.setText("09:00");
        vh.txtTime2.setText("10:30");
        vh.txtTime3.setText("12:00");
        vh.txtTime4.setText("13:30");
        vh.txtTime5.setText("15:00");
        vh.txtSubject1.setText("ENGLISH IV");
        vh.txtSubject2.setText("MACRO");
        vh.txtSubject3.setText("STRATEGIC TECHNOLOGY MANAGEMENT");
        vh.txtSubject4.setText("DATA COMMUNICATION");
        vh.txtSubject5.setText("OBJECT ORIENTED PROGRAMMING");

        AbsListView.LayoutParams layoutParams = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
                AbsListView.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                schedule_lvItem.getCurrentHeight()
        );
        vh.wrapper.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        schedule_lvItem.setWrapper(vh.wrapper);

        v.setTag(vh);

        return v;
    }

    public class viewHolder{
        LinearLayout wrapper;
        ImageView imgDay;
        CustomView_Schedule customView;
        TextView txtTime1;
        TextView txtTime2;
        TextView txtTime3;
        TextView txtTime4;
        TextView txtTime5;
        TextView txtSubject1;
        TextView txtSubject2;
        TextView txtSubject3;
        TextView txtSubject4;
        TextView txtSubject5;
    }
```

The first LinearLayout visible in the screen while others not

NOTE:: This is for a single row items of ListView

I'm currently create expandable ListView with slide animation.

This Layout will contains both before and after expand effect does.

what did I do wrong?? plz advice.

Comment: how many items scheduleLvItems contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first linearlayout is taking the full space from its parent because of `FILL_PARENT` :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.prototype.auinsight.schedual_listview"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:id="@+id/wrapper">

    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">  <===  here
```

replace it with : `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` should solve your issue.

Using a parent with heith : `wrap_content`, and a child with height `fill_parent` has unpredictable result since both rely on each other for their size.

By the way "FILL_PARENT" is deprecated, it has been renamed to "MATCH_PARENT".